# Symfony/Doctrine: Invalid PathExpression when counting OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a product entity and I want to get all Products which have offers.
The `productHasImages` is a OneToMany Relationship between `Product` and `Images`

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductHasImage", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"}))
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"sorting" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $productHasImages;
```

So I set up the querybuilder with the following options in my Form-Entity:

```
....
    ->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
                        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product',
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'label' => 'product',
                        'translation_domain' => 'product',
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($portal) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                ->select('p')
                                ->addSelect('COUNT(p.productHasImages) AS productHasImagesCount')
                                ->having('productHasImagesCount > 1');
                        }
                    ))
```

Without the Count Query, I get all entites, but with it, I get an Error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'productHasImages)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

Can someone help me with this? THANKS!

Comment: What if you do your count inside the first select ? Doesn't it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this

```
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->where('SIZE(p.productHasImages)>0');
                    }
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

"SIZE(collection) - Return the number of elements in the specified collection"